# video controls behavior on full screen mode on MS Edge

Tags: html, html5-video, fullscreen, microsoft-edge

I have a url that has videos on it. `http://cs75.tv/2012/summer`
The issue is on full screen mode on MS Edge, the controls bar is visible twice. To reproduce the issue:

On “Lectures” tab expand any Lecture. Under that lecture expand 
"Video". Then select MP4. On the pop up video player, on the bottom 
 right there are some buttons. Click on the double opposing arrows 
 which supposed to maximize video to full screen. That full screen 
 button doesn’t work on my Edge (version 42). No issues with FF and 
 chrome.

I am not able to reproduce it with a simple example. All I could understand is if the full screen is applied to a `<video>` element it works all good. But if the element happens to be a `<div>` and `<body>` it breaks the whole layout on MS Edge on full screen. Please advise if it is a bug or if it has any solution. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am available with Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 I try to follow your steps and try to produce the issue. I am able to see the control bar twice for only 1 time. I refresh the page and than it works without any issue. I made a test with simple HTML5 Video controls with Edge and find that it is working properly. We can notice that the control bar looks different than the standard control bar. It can be possible that this site using some 3rd party api for video which caused this issue with MS Edge. We can also see some warnings for video in console.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. The issue is with the control bars coming twice. Not many users would like to refresh the page or would know that the control bar will be fine on page refresh. I wouldlike to understand the reason behind this behavior and try to fix it.

Comment: We need to check that whether they are using any Api for the video or not and whats the exact code they are using it. Whether that Api is fully supported with Edge or not. If you are the developer of the site than you may try to post the sample code. If you are a user of that site than you cannot correct it from your side. You can try to provide the feedback about the issue to that site. so that developers of that site try to check for the issue.

Comment: I have another website that is behaving the same. If you have an email I can share it with you.

Comment: I just want to figure out if this behavior is due to underlying css of the website or if it is Edge specific. I dont see any issues on other browsers!

Comment: Does it mean, you seen this behavior in MS Edge with multiple websites? I made the test with HTML 5 video code but it works fine with Edge. I will made several tests again to produce the issue. If you have any sample code which can produce the issue than you can post it here. I will also make a test with it to check whether it is the issue with the Edge or not.